# CSS3 Media Queries - Chrome console

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport, meta, device-width

I'm trying to use Media Queries for various different viewport's. However it does not seem to be picking it up in my google chrome console.

I have the following code:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1920px;) {
    html, body {
        font-size: 3.5vh;
    }

    img[class="carousel-images"] {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
```

I have also included the stylesheet in my index.html along with the following meta tag...

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1" />
```

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working any help would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realised why they weren't working I had to remove the ' ; ' after defining the device px.

My syntax was wrong, I have resolved this. But thanks for any comments.